# Persistent ERESOLVE error while installing React and React-DOM for Next.js project

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, next.js

I am trying to set up a new Next.js project on my Mac (M2), but I keep running into a persistent ERESOLVE error when attempting to install react and react-dom. I've tried various troubleshooting steps but none seem to resolve the issue. Here's what I have done so far:

1. Created a new project directory and initialized a new Node.js project.
2. Attempted to install react and react-dom using the following command:

```
npm install react@^18.2.0 react-dom@^18.2.0
```

1. I encountered an ERESOLVE error indicating a dependency resolution failure.
2. Tried using the --legacy-peer-deps and --force flags as suggested in the error message but to no avail. The --force flag led to an EACCES permission denied error.
3. Deleted the node_modules directory and package-lock.json file, and retried the installation, but the ERESOLVE error persists.

Here's a snippet of the error message I am receiving:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: new-nextjs-project@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I am using the latest versions of Node.js (v21.1.0) and npm (v10.2.0). Any advice on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Is there anything else I could try to get past this ERESOLVE error and successfully set up my Next.js project?

Answer (score 0):

You can let npm install it without specifying versions, npm will try to install latest version anyway

```
npm install react react-dom
```

If that does not help, try to remove package-lock.json, and install it again